# How to - comparing chars in a char array to make sure user didn't input a number

Tags: c++, arrays, char, integer

I am doing a class project for a banking system. One of the tasks is to make sure that a user doesn't enter a numerical character when putting in their name, and vice versa when putting in say, DOB, and or phone number.

I am using a char array to get first and last name, but I want to check the user input to find if they accidentally entered in a number for example:

- Jason (accept)
- j3son (reject)

```
cout << "*************************" << endl;
cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
cin.getline(nameFirst, 20);
cout << endl;
```

this prompts user for first name. I want to send it to a function

```
bool checkName();
```

and I suppose have some sort of loop to check all the elements of the array (nameFirst) to see if there is a numerical value placed. and if so. to then return something back and use that return value to decide if the use has put an invalid entry or not.

I've been stumped. I cannot find anything that resembles this. Everything I have found was for `int`s only, but nothing to compare an `int` to a `char`.

Comment: [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and a loop. If you are feeling adventurous, you can replace the loop with [`std::none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: Do you also want to check if the first character of the name is uppercase?

Comment: Please expand the code to show your `nameFirst` declaration!

Comment: "Everything I have found was for `int`s only." -- Are you referring to e.g. `isdigit` taking an `int` parameter? That is an ancient "hack" so the function can cater to `EOF` being passed as well. You cast the character to check to `unsigned char` before passing it to `isdigit`. -- Also, don't use char arrays. Use `std::string nameFirst` and `std::getline( std::cin, nameFirst )`...

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string nameFirst;
    std::getline( std::cin, nameFirst );

    // This will work with nameFirst being char[] as well,
    // but you REALLY should use std::string...
    if ( std::any_of( std::begin( nameFirst ), std::end( nameFirst ), [](unsigned char c){return std::isdigit(c);} ) )
    {
        std::cout << "I found a digit!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can loop over the input and can check the ASCII values. If the input falls under the range of numbers then its a number. Same strategy goes for chars. Best way would be to use inbuilt functions like `isDigit`. https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isdigit

Comment: Using ASCII codes is not recommended. it is much easier for a reader to interpret the intent of `'0'` than 47, makes it easier to insert a typo, for example ASCII `'0'` does NOT map to 47, and the target system may not use ASCII as its character encoding. Prefer to use the `isdigit` function which will handle all of the edge cases and unusual situations the target presents for you.

Comment: Yes exactly, we can use inbuilt function to get our job done.